# Attempting to exchange two sections of an image

Tags: java, image

I am trying to swap the values of two sections of an image in a specific fashion: I want to move one block of pixes to the right 225 pixels, and take the block that was there and move it to the left 225 at the same time. However, it looks like the only transformation that takes hold is the first one:

```
public void exchange() {
    int[][] stablePic = picArray.clone();

        for (int i = 80; i < 230; i++)
        {
                for (int j = 50; j < 250; j++)
                {

                    picArray[i][j] = stablePic[i][j+225];

                    picArray[i][j+225] = stablePic[i][j];

                }
        }

}
```

"picArray" is initialized earlier in the code - this compiles and runs, but only makes the first exchange - the second portion of the image still has the appearance of the first portion. Is there any way to have both transformations take place at once?

Comment: No need for the "Java" in the title. The tag is sufficient.

Comment: Is that all your relevant code?  What is the size of picArray?

Comment: Please indent your code correctly with all necessary brackets. And post more relevant code. A [SSCCE](http://ssce.org) will get you help faster

Comment: It's really hard to tell exactly what the code is supposed to do, or what it's actually doing, without a compilable example

Comment: no need for test `& l > 250` as you are already starting with `l=275` and it only grows

Comment: A few edits: cleaned up the code and removed `& l > 250` - that was an early attempt to solve half of the problem. The size of picArray is the number of pixels in the image. Unfortunately, the framework of the assignment means if I shared the code that would compile I would have to post code that belongs to somebody else. I suspect my issue is a bit more fundamental: it must be an array or loop issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the second fragment is the only one working? It seems to me that is the first one which is working.

To copy one array to other array don't just assign it. Use 2 for-loops for this, and when you see it works, investigate about how to replace the inner for-loop with `Arrays.copyOf`.

Here you have:

```
int[][] stablePic = picArray;
```

Which makes both variables point to the same memory, then when you modify your `picArray` you are modifying your `stablePic` also.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to swap two sections of an image for understanding purpose just take it as how can you swap two variables i.e

```
int a=10;
int b=20;
int temp ;//take a temp variable for swapping

temp =a;
a=b;
b=temp;
```

like this you have to take a temporary array.For swapping .in your code second one is working because it is overriding with the previous one.

Comment: How do you do this in a 2d array?

Comment: lot of techniques one is take a one temporary 2D array before swapping first second part to temp array then copy from second to first then from temp to second.